# Is the magnetic field calculated by Ampere's Law only because of the currents crossing the loop?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

> In Ampere's Law,
>
> $$\oint \vec B \cdot \mathrm d \vec l = \mu I$$
>
> the current outside the curve is not included on the right hand side
>   of the equation.*

Does it mean that the magnetic field 'B' calculated by using Ampere's Law, gives the contribution of only the currents crossing the area bounded by the curve?

Answer (score 2):

In general, Ampere's law does not necessarily give the value of the magnetic field.  It only gives the integral of the field along a closed path.  That integral can sometimes be used to deduce the magnetic field at any given point, but only if you know something about the magnetic field from symmetry or other considerations.  For example, along a circular path (radius $r$) around a long straight wire, symmetry requires that the magnetic field has constant magnitude $B$ and is always tangent to the path, and so the integral is just $B$ multiplied by the length of the circular path, which is the circumference $2\pi r$.  Then the left-hand side of the Ampere's law equation is $B\cdot 2\pi r$, and so $B=\mu_0i/2\pi r$.  There are only a couple of other examples of symmetry where Ampere's law is really useful: the ideal solenoid and the toroid.  All of these are worked out in most textbooks.

Comment: There's one more example where Ampère's Law can be used directly:  the infinite planar sheet of current.